# How to get informations as with GET-PSDrive on drives mounted in NTFS folder without driveletter

Tags: powershell, directory, drive

How can I get free space and other informations about drives which have no drive letter, the drives were mounted in a NTFS folder with the disk management console, local on a win 10 workstation ?
I need a solution in powershell, can somebody give me a hint?

Comment: How about: `Get-Volume`? I strongly believe that there may be a class you can call on to get that info via CIM.

Answer (score 2):

This is a really tricky one!  The WMI namespace `Win32_MountPoint` has the info we need to see which drives are mounted as a disk drive or a folder.

The bottom entry is an example of a drive mounted as a folder.

```
#Use Get-WmiObject Win32_MountPoint if the below fails
PS> Get-CimInstance Win32_MountPoint 


Directory             : Win32_Directory (Name = "H:\")
Volume                : Win32_Volume (DeviceID = "\\?\Volume{38569fb2-42e2-4359-8b42-1807...)
PSComputerName        :
CimClass              : root/cimv2:Win32_MountPoint
CimInstanceProperties : {Directory, Volume}
CimSystemProperties   : Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimSystemProperties

Directory             : Win32_Directory (Name = "C:\thumb")
Volume                : Win32_Volume (DeviceID = "\\?\Volume{e5d29a99-c6c2-11eb-b472-4ccc...)
PSComputerName        :
CimClass              : root/cimv2:Win32_MountPoint
CimInstanceProperties : {Directory, Volume}
CimSystemProperties   : Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimSystemProperties
```

With this info in mind...we can pass the DeviceID info over to another command to find out how much disk space there is.

```
get-volume | ? Path -eq  $mount.Volume.DeviceID

DriveLetter FriendlyName FileSystemType DriveType HealthStatus OperationalStatus  SizeRemaining    Size
----------- ------------ -------------- --------- ------------ -----------------  -------------    ----
                         FAT32          Removable Warning      Full Repair Needed       3.44 GB 3.74 GB
```

Now, let's make this into a function where you pass in the mount path and we return the info on the actual disk.

```
Function Get-MountedFolderInfo{
    param($MountPath)

    $mount = gcim Win32_MountPoint | where directory -like "*$MountPath*"

    if ($null -eq $mount){
        return "no mounted file found at $MountPath"
    }

    $volumeInfo = get-volume | Where-Object Path -eq $mount.Volume.DeviceID
    
    if ($null -eq $VolumeInfo){
        "Could not retrieve info for:"
        return $mount
    }

    $volumeInfo
}
Get-MountedFolderInfo -MountPath C:\thumb

DriveLetter FriendlyName FileSystemType DriveType HealthStatus OperationalStatus  SizeRemaining    Size
----------- ------------ -------------- --------- ------------ -----------------  -------------    ----
                         FAT32          Removable Warning      Full Repair Needed       3.44 GB 3.74 GB
```